# What is the difference between ng build --prod and ng build --env=prod?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What is the difference between `ng build --prod` and `ng build --env=prod`?

My understanding is

- `ng build --env=prod` only set environment settings inside `environment.prod.ts`, whereas
- `ng build --prod` runs the `--env=prod` and does AOT, bundle, Minification Uglification, Dead code elimination

Is this correct?

Comment: Which version of the Angular CLI are you talking about?

Comment: That looks correct to me.  Keep in mind that --env becomes --configuration in Angular 6, so it would be ng build --configuration=prod --aot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are correct.

ng build --env=prod / ng build --configuration=prod will change the project configuration to the configurations set in the environment.prod.ts file. It will not do any AOT, minification etc.

ng build --prod will run a production build, meaning it will do bundling, minification, AOT etc

Comment: This is not entirely true. While you are correct that ng build --env=prod will set the environment to environment.prod.ts, but not do any AOT, minification etc. This is the case for angular cli v5 and lower. In angular 6+, --configuration=prod is an alias for --prod https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/05/04/angular-cli-6.0/

Comment: This used to be so simple, kinda like not having to mark everything with question marks in typescript.